# How do I insert a template while interpolating in Angular 4?

Tags: angular

I try to implement nested translations in Angular (content of a link has translation, and this link has to be embedded into another translation), and it all boils down to me to the following scenario:

```ts
<ng-template #link>
  <a href="#">Test</a>
</ng-template>

<p>Your link: {{link}}</p>
```

However, in the above case `link` is the TemplateRef object. So my question is, how do I replace the content of the braces with the contents of the TemplateRef?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: what is the resulting html that you expect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**update Angular 5**

`ngOutletContext` was renamed to `ngTemplateOutletContext`

See also https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#500-beta5-2017-08-29

**original**

`NgTemplateOutlet` does what you want:

```ts
<p>Your link: <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="link"></ng-container></p>
```

You can also pass context data to be used for bindings inside the template.

https://angular.io/api/common/NgTemplateOutlet

Searching for `NgTemplateOutlet` on StackOverflow should provide several more examples.

**update**

```ts
<ng-template #linkTemplate let-link>
  <a href="#">{{link}}</a>
</ng-template>

<p>Your link: <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="linkTemplate; context: {$implicit: link}"></ng-container></p>
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/TfnhdtJBi8XDiJvx3hBt?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer! I have a follow-up question: `Your link: {{link}}` is actually the translation that comes from external API, and I would rather not have `<ng-container></ng-container>` among my translations and I'd like to keep it as `{{link}}` though, is there any way to enforce it?

Comment: Sorry, then I probably don't understand the question. `<ng-template #link>` causes a name collision, because `#link` introduces a template variable that refers to the `<ng-template>` What are you using `#link` for then?

Comment: I updated my answer. Still not sure though if this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can also fit a template with condition in below way. incase you want to load your template in else condition.

```
    <ng-content *ngIf="!content; else link">

    </ng-content>
    <ng-template #link>
      <div [innerHtml]="otherContent">

      </div>
    </ng-template>
  </div>
```